# How to determine velocity function for a stream of water from a broken container?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

Let's say we have a cylindrical container with height H and base radius R, completely filled with water that has a small hole in it at the very bottom, which is parralel to the ground. Let's say that the container is standing on stands above the ground. The hole has a radius of r.

Obviously, r is negligible in comparison to H, but still large eneough to prevent the surface tension of water to keep the water inside the container.

How would you go about computing the function of the velocity of the stream of escaping water with respect to time?

Edit:
So, considering the below input, this yields:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that velocity depends upon height.

Edit: got it now, exit speed is sqrt(2gh)...(you can multiply this by 0,97 according to engineering formulas). Inserting, integrating, applying boundary conditions yields the result. I will be posting it when I'm finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open-ended question; we can assume the hole is sufficiently large
that surface tension doesn't hold the water inside the vessel, and might even
assume that there's little viscous drag at the hole, in which case it becomes
a conservation-of-energy problem.

The water coming out of the hole cannot have higher velocity than if it
fell 'h' (initially, h = H) distance to the hole location.   That
gives us an at-the-hole velocity (but it's a function of h, it changes
with time).   Viscous drag, which loses energy, is going
to modify this, if we want to get into that detail (but let's not do that).

$$ {{dM * {v(t)}^2} \over 2 }= dM * g * h(t) $$

And, if the hole area is pi*r^2, the volume escaping per second is the water velocity times pi * r^2.

Finally, the height h is initially H, and varies with time as the leak
removes water,  $$dh(t)/dt ={{- (pi \times r^2 \times v(t) )} \over {pi \times R^2}} $$

We know  two other equations,

$$ h(0) = H$$

and we may want to solve for T, the time at which

$$h(T) = 0$$

because at that time, the flow stops.   This is mathematically soluble.